# How to remove child jdialog reference from the parent dialog Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, removechild

I want to remove the child dialog from the parent dialog **Without clicking on the child dialog**.  And Without editing the parent dialog creation source code. The parent dialog is reusing and it creates only once.

Comment: So you want to close the JDialog?

Comment: yes. the child dialog. The parent dialog is reusing and It creates only once.

Comment: What is the context? Can you post more code?

Comment: Child dialog is only a notification and it should be disappear when close the parent. Again opening the parent dialog should not open the notification again.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Also, what do you mean by reference? And what is `notifiactionChildDialogList` for?

Comment: you can use the `windowListener`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your answer  :

```
package stack;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DialogShower implements WindowListener {

  JFrame frame;
  JButton showButton;
  ParentDialog parentDialog;
  boolean fristTimeOpen = true;

  public DialogShower() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    parentDialog = new ParentDialog();
    parentDialog.addWindowListener(this);

    showButton = new JButton("Show me");
    showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (fristTimeOpen) {
          parentDialog.childDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
        parentDialog.setVisible(true);
      }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(showButton);
    frame.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public class ParentDialog extends JDialog {

    ChildDialog childDialog;

    public ParentDialog() {
      super(frame, "ParentDialog", true);
      childDialog = new ChildDialog();
    }

    public class ChildDialog extends JDialog {

      JLabel label;

      public ChildDialog() {
        super(ParentDialog.this, "childDailg", false);
        label = new JLabel("Notification : Dialog");
        getContentPane().add(label);
        setLocation(300, 300);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("2");
  }

  @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    fristTimeOpen = false;
    parentDialog.childDialog.dispose();
  }

  @Override
  public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DialogShower();
  }
}
```

I created two dialog when you click on button `Show me` it open parent Dialog as well as child Dialog. When you close the parent Dialog it close child Dialog automatically. I use `WindowListener` to perform action on parent Dialog close.When you again open the parent Dialog it doesn't open the child Dialog;

Comment: Thank for your help. but in my case, I can't edit the parent dialog.